# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' java.io.IOException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, path

I don't know how I got in to this, but I think the problem is the Java binary path... The path from flutter doctor is different from the one in the Exception.
Either when I run existing projects or I create new project and try to run it it still gives the same error.

> e: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon"): CreateProcess
>   , The system cannot find the file specified
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (10 days ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5556 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
```

After this problem I tried to solve it by:

- Upgrading flutter
- Changing the jdk path on Android Studio to Java_Home from: 
  [java.io.IOException: Cannot run program CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705525/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot).

Answer (score 2):

kill all about OpenJDK process, then in folder "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\", remove jre folder and restart your code editor